# Как получить права доступа в библиотеках winreg и win32api?

Tags: python

**Задача:**
Произвести импорт и экспорт `.reg` файла\ветви реестра.
Рассматриваю библиотеки `winreg` и `win32api`, а конкретно:

`winreg.SaveKey` выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\export.py", line 84, in <module>
    Reg.Export(r"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE", r"D:\\add2.reg")
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\export.py", line 80, in Export
    winreg.SaveKey(key, File)
OSError: [WinError 1314] Клиент не обладает требуемыми правами
```

`win32api.RegSaveKey` выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\214354.py", line 14, in <module>
    RegSaveKey(key, "D:\\add4.reg", None)
pywintypes.error: (1314, 'RegSaveKey', 'Клиент не обладает требуемыми правами.')
```

Ответа в гугле не нашел.
Запуск .py файла из командной строки от Администратора не помогает.
Запуск .py файла из PyScripter от Администратора не помогает.
Запуск .py файла из IDLE Pyton от Администратора не помогает.
Запуск .py файла из Pyton.exe от Администратора не помогает.

**Вопросы:**
Так как собственно получить эти права?
Что лучше использовать для импорта\экспорта?